# Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET Web Application Designer Bugged

Tags: c#, asp.net

My ASP.NET web application solution has changed. On the first picture you see that the solution has Designer Split and Source, however on the second picture there is only design and source. The problem is in the first one in the designer i could easily drag and drop and modify the design of the web page by dragging elements etc. But when it changed to the second picture, i cant do the same thing and im much more limited. Im not sure what caused the change.

[image: Solution]
[image: pic 2]

Comment: _"The problem is in the first one in the designer i could easily drag and drop and modify the design of the web page by dragging elements etc"_ - Web-design really hasn't worked like that since IE6 and we stopped using `<table>`-for-layout... I'm surprised that today (in 2024) you felt a WYSIWYG was _ever actually working_ for you (not to mention all of the things they inherently _can't do_ like SPA, CSS `@media` and container-queries, nontrivial selectors, etc. My suggestion to you is to invest the time in taking-off the training wheels.

Comment: Not true, in our industry a visual drag + drop design approach will ALWAYS win in the market place - ALWAYS! The issue been for the last 10 years the HTML5 standards and css was a moving target. Now that the dust has settled, and the standards are quite solid, then the trend back to GUI design based will return to our industry with a vengeance. This is especially so now that what you build via GUI drag + drop will be responsive based on the solid and not so fast changing HTML5 standards.

Comment: You think people in print industry hand code their PostScript? (don't make me laugh). The same will occur for HTML5 + css. Why do you think Adobe was trying to and going to buy figma? Because they know that HTML5 + css and a GUI designer threatens their PostScript eco system. The same will occur for web design, and the movement back to GUI based design will win the day HANDS DOWN!!!! Hand coding markup is like hand code assembler in the mainframe days - it makes ZERO sense to do as such. The big feature for vs2022 is chrome based web forms designer - it just didn't support drag + drop correct

Comment: The buggy designer like the answer indicated is a new one introduced in VS2022, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/ and it remains a preview build. I don't know why it was enabled for your project but by default it's disabled. Besides, investing your efforts in WebForms which hasn't been upgraded significantly after ASP.NET MVC is at your own risks.  Migrating to Blazor/MVC/Razor Pages has been recommended for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a new web forms desinger and layout for vs2022.

It is REALLY nice in which a new HTML rendering engine based on the Chrome engine.

However, it does not support drag + drop well, so it is with great sadness that I suggest you revert back to the older legacy designer.

So, tools->options->Web Forms Designer.

And this setting:

[image]

So, while the new live preview is REALLY amazing, and renders your markup without having to run it?

Without the drag + drop from the tool box playing nice, then I still use and prefer the legacy web forms designer.

Change the above setting, and you have to exit + re-start Visual Studio, but the older legacy designer is still avaiable.